# "You'll never be too much for someone who can't get enough of you." What does that mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "You'll never be too much for someone who can't get enough of you."

I saw this sentence on Twitter with no more context, or detail. Someone asked me "what does that mean?" We are non-native speakers so I think this sentence is somewhat a lyric or catchphrase.
Therefore I did googling and found that so many Twitter users quoted this sentence.

[image]

Comment: Which part of the sentence is confusing to you? What is your thinking about what it could mean? It helps us write better answers if we understand which parts are hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

**Too much** is not like wearing too much red, or sleeping too much. It generally means *annoying*. So it's more like joking around with people in ways that annoy them because it's fun (for you) to see them get annoyed.

That is *too much*.

**Cannot get enough** is something you *always* want. Like a song you play on repeat for hours, or a TV show you like so much that it becomes part of your life. When you *cannot get enough* of something, you have a hard time imagining your life without it.

So, if someone loves you so much that they cannot get enough of you, you can never be too much for them.

Comment: Your last sentence may read better as "So if someone loves you so much that they always want more of you, you can never be too much for them" - otherwise you're explaining the phrase by using the phrase itself